# How do I make a circle in React that aligns with page-size and has text centered?

Tags: css, reactjs

Let's start right off with my code

```
const circle = {
    display: 'table',
    textAlign: 'center',
    height: 160,
    width: 160,
    borderRadius: 80,
    color: 'white'
};
return (
    <div className="bg-info" style={circle}>
        <div style={{display: 'table-cell', verticalAlign: 'middle'}}>
            <h2 className="text-white">{props.alarms}</h2>
            <div>Total Alarms</div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

I tried searching around on StackOverflow but found no results. This is how it's display on the page
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJMRM.png)

Not only is the text not-centered, the circle also doesn't align to the page resizing since I have the height + width fixed

What can I do to fix this? I used the display of table to try to get it to center as you can see but it failed. Also the text above Total Alarms in the picture (Total Alerts) will also be getting a circle of it's own with a different background color once I fix this.

I have react-bootstrap installed aswell if that helps with any of this

EDIT: I removed some irrelevant data in the code

Comment: What is your expected result? Are you just trying to center the text horizontally and vertically in a circle? Have you tried inspecting your DOM to see what other CSS is being applied against it to yield the undesirable result?

Comment: @DrewReese That's exactly what I'm trying to do, I've tried messing around with the CSS in devtools but hasn't worked. If you can look at my screenshot, I am doing the horizontally with textAlign and the vertically with verticalAlign on the JSX styling but it's not working the way I want it to be as you can see

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to achieve centered content, and vw for the sizing:

```
<div class="circle">
 <div>
  <h2>Text1</h2>
  <h3>Text2</h3>
 </div>
</div>

.circle {
  background: blue;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 70vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.circle > div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is link to a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7gk1tx0p/